# Adding new library

Tags: codeigniter

http://127.0.0.1/masterlinkci2/admin/cpages/pages

**I get this error message:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Cpages::$gionda_date
>
> Filename: controllers/Cpages.php
>
> Line Number: 200

**Line 200:**  `$data['gionda_date'] = $this->gionda_date->g_date();`

controllers/Cpages.php

```
public function pages() { 

    $data['pagessuccess'] = ''; 

    $data['pages'] = $this->Mpages->call_pages();

    $data['gionda_date'] = $this->gionda_date->g_date();

    $this->load->view('pages', $data); 

}
```

**libraries/gionda_date.php**

```
class Gionda_date {

private $CI;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
}

public function g_date()
{
    $datestring = 'Year: %Y Month: %m Day: %d - %h:%i %a';
    return $datestring;
}
```

Can anyone help me fix the error messages?

Comment: you only have to declare gionda_date in declaration class in controllers/Cpages.php .

Comment: Try using add $this->load->library('gionda_date'); or in the __construct area of controller

Comment: you can also load libraries directly in your constructor like: require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/librarystartpage.php');

Comment: Also the file name for libraries first letter uppercase only `libraries/Gionda_date.php`

Answer (score 1):

Is you library loaded in your Cpages controller?

```
$this->gionda_date->g_date();
```

edited because of comment here is the most likely solution:

```
$this->load->library('gionda_date')
```

Comment: I find an answer to this post.  Thanks all.